# How to get default values for fields in DB2 query?

Tags: database, db2

I used the query

```
"DESCRIBE TABLE Mytable"
```

but it doesnt work.Then I got the structure of mytable by using

```
 "Select distinct(name), ColType, Length, nulls, default from qsys2.SYSCOLUMNS where tbname = 'Mytable'"
```

It worked but I got the default as yes/no. How can I get the default value for each fields

Comment: What DB2 version/platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the DDL of a table via the db2look command, and then retrieve the default values for each column if any.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html

```
db2look -d yourDB -e -tw Mytable% -o db2look.sql
```